# On the verge of UB - server/client memory deletion program

Tags: c++, memory-management, undefined-behavior

I have a couple of unrelated classes working together using listeners. They both keep a copy of their respective virtual interface, simplified like this:

```
    struct Base
    {
        struct IFormat
        {
            virtual int formatVal(string &) = 0;
        };

        void addFmt(IFormat * fmt)
        {
            if (!fmts.contains(fmt))
                fmts.push_back(fmt);
        }

        void removeFmt(IFormat * fmt)
        {
            auto it = fmts.find(fmt);
            if (it != fmts.end())
                fmts.erase(it);
        }

        int getValueFromFmts(string & input)
        {
            // this is getting called once in a while
            int ret(0);
            for (auto fmt : fmts)
                ret += fmt->formatVal(input);
        }

        virtual ~Base()
        {
            // what now? something probably has a reference to me.
        }
    private:
        vector<IFormat *> fmts;

    };


    struct Editor : public Base::IFormat
    {
        Editor(Base * base)
            : base(base)
        {
            base->addFmt(this);
        }

        ~Editor()
        {
            // base might be deleted!
            base->removeFmt(this);
        }

        virtual int formatVal(string &) override { ... }

    private:
        Base * base;
    };
```

The problem, as stated in the code: Either class may be deleted at any point. The editor can unregister it's formatter, but if the base class disappears firstly, things get bad. This is a problem i have many places (it is GUI code), so i needed a generic solution. I figured that all the 'base' classes can derive from a generic deletion notifier (server), and implement the notify mechanism as clients of this server. I created this piece of code, which works wonderfully:

```
template<typename Derived>
class DestructionServer
{
public:
    typedef Derived type;

    class ObjectProxy
    {
    public:
        ObjectProxy(const Derived * serverToPresent) 
            : server(serverToPresent)
        {}

        bool operator == (const Derived * other) const
        {
            return server == other;
        }

        bool operator != (const Derived * other) const
        {
            return server != other;
        }

    private:
        const Derived * server;
    };

    class Client
    {
        friend class DestructionServer<Derived>;
    public:
        Client()
            : server(nullptr)
        {

        }

        typedef DestructionServer Server;

        virtual ~Client()
        {
            if (server)
                server->removeClientDestructor(this);
        }

        virtual void onObjectDestruction(const ObjectProxy & destroyedObject) = 0;

    private:
        void onDestruction(const Derived * derivedServer)
        {
            if (!server)
                throw std::runtime_error("Fatal error: DestructionServer::Client has no server!");
            // derivedServer should be able to downcast to server, without conversion
            if (derivedServer != server)
                throw std::runtime_error("Fatal error: derivedServer does not derive from server!");

            // forget reference to server
            server = nullptr;
            // return an unmodifiable reference to the server
            onObjectDestruction(derivedServer);
        }
        Server * server;
    };


    void removeClientDestructor(Client * client)
    {
        auto it = std::find(clients.begin(), clients.end(), client);
        if (it != clients.end())
        {
            clients.erase(it);
        }
    }

    void addClientDestructor(Client * client)
    {
        if (client && !std::contains(clients, client))
        {
            clients.push_back(client);
            // this only happens if a client is loaded into multiple servers
            // or the client is trying to add itself multiple times to the same server.
            if (client->server)
                throw std::runtime_error("Fatal error: Client already has a server!");
            client->server = this;
        }
    }

    virtual ~DestructionServer()
    {
        for (Client * client : clients)
        {
            // would like to use a dynamic_cast here to check the upcast,
            // but it is not possible since
            // ((Derived*)this) is actually deconstructed at this point...
            // or can static_cast handle this?
            // in effect this is UB, but it 'works'
            if (const Derived * derivedServer = static_cast<const Derived *>(this))
            {
                client->onDestruction(derivedServer);
            }
            else
            {
                // in fact, the typeid() shouldn't work as well, here?
                throw std::runtime_error(
                    std::string("Fatal error: ") + typeid(this).name() +
                    " doesn't derive from " + typeid(DestructionServer<Derived> *).name()
                    );
            }
        }

    }
protected:
    // make it impossible to construct this class without 
    // deriving from this class.
    DestructionServer() {};

private:
    std::vector<Client *> clients;
};
```

Now i can rewrite the example like this, and keep it completely deletion-safe:

```
    struct Base : public DestructionServer<Base>
    {
        struct IFormat : public Client
        {
            virtual int formatVal(string &) = 0;
        };

        void addFmt(IFormat * fmt)
        {
            if (!fmts.contains(fmt))
            {
                addClientDestructor(fmt);
                fmts.push_back(fmt);
            }
        }

        void removeFmt(IFormat * fmt)
        {
            auto it = fmts.find(fmt);
            if (it != fmts.end())
            {
                fmts.erase(it);
            }
        }

        int getValueFromFmts(string & input)
        {
            // this is getting called once in a while
            int ret(0);
            for (auto fmt : fmts)
                ret += fmt->formatVal(input);
        }

        virtual ~Base()
        {
            // DestructionServer automatically notifies all
            // objects that set a formatter to this class.
        }
    private:
        vector<IFormat *> fmts;

    };


    struct Editor : public Base::IFormat
    {
        Editor(Base * base)
            : base(base)
        {
            base->addFmt(this);
        }

        ~Editor()
        {
            // base is now null if it is deleted
            if(base)
                base->removeFmt(this);
        }

        virtual int formatVal(string &) override { ... }
        virtual void onObjectDestruction(const Base::ObjectProxy & object)
        {
            if (object == base)
            {
                // ok, base is destructed now. set it to null and go kill our self
                base = nullptr;
                delete this;
            }
        }
    private:
        Base * base;
    };
```

**The problem**

If you made it through the wall of code and read the comments - thank you - you probably noticed I'm casting the this-pointer from the base deconstructor to the derived type, and calling back the notifiers. Knowing fully well that the pointer is most probably garbage (half deconstructed), i designed the ObjectProxy class to keep the clients from using the object (though they still can if they have a copy, obviously).

The only thing the ObjectProxy allows is to compare the value of the pointer to another, of the same type (so the clients can check which object was destructed), so I'm not sure if it's actually undefined behaviour - it is never dereferencing the pointer.

Also, can the upcast ever fail at runtime - do i need a dynamic_cast? I'm pretty sure the static_cast disallows giving unrelated template types to DestructionServer, so bad types will fail at compile time.

Any other ideas for making this system work is also welcome...

Comment: You probably want a `std::set` instead of `std::vector<IFormat *>`. O(log N).

Comment: Yes, possibly. Optimization are the least of my concerns right now, though.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a typical case for `std::shared_ptr`. Obviously you'd need to explicitly reset the shared pointers to prevent cyclic references, or use `std::weak_ptr` in one direction. The current solution seems to suffer from excessive complexity.

[edit]
You may even look into a fancy technique. You can have multiple `shared_ptr` of different types share a single use count. Hence, `shared_ptr<IFormat>` can share the use count with `shared_ptr<Base>`. Hence, you can hand out either pointer to client code, and even the users of `shared_ptr<IFormat>` will keep `Base` alive. And since you set up `Base` to own `IFormat`, everything becomes trivial.

Comment: Im trying to imagine how you would do this - are you saying the editor should be constructed using a shared_pointer to the base? Note that it is completely valid behaviour that the base is destructed before the editor (and it doesn't have to delete itself)

Comment: @Shaggi: How would the base be destructed if the editor still has a shared_ptr to it? Remember, when using `shared_ptr` you never call `delete`.

Comment: My formulations are probably a bit vague; I'm sorry. It is _intended_ that the base class may be deleted at any point.

Consider an actual case, where the base is some arbitrary control/button which displays a value, and the editor is a static part of the GUI that can attach to controls (which derive from the base). The editors purpose is to adjust the control in some different way.

Now, the user may 'close', hide or do whatever to the controls, which will have the effect of resetting the editor.

Comment: I think that you don't actually mean the base class will be `delete`'ed. Instead, you mean that the using code will indicate it's done using the base class. And that can also be signaled via `shared_ptr.reset()`.

Comment: But I dont want to keep the base alive. If the user clicks X on a window, the window is deleted including the contents (and controls, which derives from bases). Meanwhile, the editor, in another window, still exists and should merely adopt to the situation.

I could probably use a weak_ptr to check the existance of the base object, but since we're (may) be dealing with windows that i don't control the deletion of (unless i override the message system in the library, which seems silly) i can't really use shared_ptrs.

Comment: Then I don't get the requirements, sorry. It's unclear to me exactly which objects should stay alive while other objects are alive. And in fact I suspect that you may not be that sure either. That doesn't take away the main message: once you have figured out how object lifetimes relate, it's trivial to design the relation using `std::unique_ptr` (single control of lifetime), `std::shared_ptr` (shared control) and `std::weak_ptr (no control, but safe check if other object is still alive)

Comment: The point is, i dont and can't control the lifetime of the base object. However, i need to react to it's deletion so i dont use dangling pointers.

Comment: @Shaggi: then use `std::weak_ptr`. It solves exactly that problem.